# Prevent $mdDialog (prompt dialog) to CONFIRM on press Enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

**SCENARIO**

I have created a `$mdDialog` (prompt dialog) where user can write a *message* and on confirm it sends an *Email*. Here is the snippet that creates the dialog

```
function requestToEditProfile() {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title($translate.instant('LABEL_608'))
        .textContent($translate.instant('LABEL_607'))
        .ariaLabel('Request to edit profile')
        .placeholder($translate.instant('LABEL_608'))
        .ok($translate.instant('REQUEST'))
        .cancel($translate.instant('CANCEL'));

    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(content) {
        var form = {"form": {"product_id":vm.id, "content": content}};
        srv.sendEditRequest(form).then(onRequestSuccess, onRequestError);
    });
  ...
}
```

in frontend it'd look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntT5G.png).

**QUESTION**

The problem is that message could get very long and the fact that user might want to press Enter at times. It seems that by default the `$mdDialog` is triggering `confirm` on press Enter.

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent/change this behaviour?